# Access MailChimp forms

Tags: 8, emails

I currently have a form that it is fully loaded from my Mailchimp Account. I configured it for display as a page using mailchimp configuration page (admin/config/services/mailchimp/signup). Then when I was trying to access it with no admin permissions I got `Not authorized to access this page` message.

Giving `Access all Mailchimp Signup Pages` permission to anonymous users fix this problem but it specify that have security implications and I think it is a wrong solution.

I searched all the drupal interface and was not able to find it on either side (Content, contact forms, etc...). This element it's only present on signup forms list (admin/config/services/mailchimp/signup) and there isn't any permissions configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Recently found a FAQ from Drupal Mailchimp módule [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2793241)
It says:

> Q: How do I create anonymous signup forms on the site as either a page
>   or a block?
>
> A: Head to this path admin/config/services/mailchimp/signup/add, fill out the form and
>   click on “Block”, “Page”, or both Display Modes.
>
> Block - ...
>
> Page - enter a path for which you’d
>   like the signup form to appear, and click “Save”. In order to make
>   SignUp pages available to anonymous users, head over to where
>   permissions are assigned (admin/people/permissions), and check the
>   appropriate boxes next to the permission marked “Access all Mailchimp
>   Signup Pages.”

So this means that I should ignore that warning.